# how does /etc/init.d/networking restart cause wpa_supplicant to be run using the previous configurations?

Tags: linux, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

**Background:**

I use Debian Lenny and have two WiFi interfaces. I use a generic configurations on `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        network 10.0.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.5.1
        network 192.168.5.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.25
```

So it has no sign about the `wpa_supplicant`.

I use wpa_supplicant (v2.0) manually to connect them to a WLAN via `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` (for wlan0) and `/etc/wpa_supplicant2.conf` (for wlan1).

**Problem:**

While the wifi interfaces are connected to WLANs, I do

```
ip link set wlan0 down
ip link set wlan1 up
rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan1
```

Then I do `ip link set wlan0 (and 1) up`. In that case, the iwconfig shows that the wifi interfaces are not connected to any network.

After that, I run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. When the process is completed, iwconfig shows that the wifi interfaces are connected to the WLANs that they were previously connected.

**Question:**

How come `/etc/init.d/networking restart` cause wpa_supplicant to be run by using the .config file for the interface that were used before (wpa_suppliant.conf for wlan0 and wpa_supplicant2.conf for wlan1)? I repeated this procedure many times and each time the wifi interfaces are connected to the same network that are defined on the .config files.

**What I have done:**

**1)** I suspected that `/etc/init.d/networking` script uses wpa_supplicant somehow. Therefore, I took a look at the script:

```
     #!/bin/sh -e
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          networking
    # Required-Start:    mountkernfs ifupdown $local_fs
    # Required-Stop:     ifupdown $local_fs
    # Default-Start:     S
    # Default-Stop:      0 6
    # Short-Description: Raise network interfaces.
    ### END INIT INFO
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

[ -x /sbin/ifup ] || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

process_options() {
    [ -e /etc/network/options ] || return 0
    log_warning_msg "/etc/network/options still exists and it will be IGNORED! R
ead README.Debian of netbase."
}

check_network_file_systems() {
    [ -e /proc/mounts ] || return 0

    exec 9<&0 < /proc/mounts
    while read DEV MTPT FSTYPE REST; do
        case $DEV in
        /dev/nbd*|/dev/nd[a-z]*|/dev/etherd/e*)
            log_warning_msg "not deconfiguring network interfaces: network devic
es still mounted."
            exit 0
            ;;
        esac
        case $FSTYPE in
        nfs|nfs4|smbfs|ncp|ncpfs|cifs|coda|ocfs2|gfs|pvfs|pvfs2|fuse.httpfs|fuse
.curlftpfs)
            log_warning_msg "not deconfiguring network interfaces: network file 
systems still mounted."
            exit 0
            ;;
        esac
    done
    exec 0<&9 9<&-
}

case "$1" in
start)

        process_options

        log_action_begin_msg "Configuring network interfaces"
        if ifup -a; then
            log_action_end_msg $?
        else
            log_action_end_msg $?
        fi
        ;;

stop)
        check_network_file_systems

        log_action_begin_msg "Deconfiguring network interfaces"
        if ifdown -a --exclude=lo; then
            log_action_end_msg $?
        else
            log_action_end_msg $?
        fi
        ;;

force-reload|restart)
        process_options

        log_action_begin_msg "Reconfiguring network interfaces"
        ifdown -a --exclude=lo || true
        if ifup -a --exclude=lo; then
            log_action_end_msg $?
        else
            log_action_end_msg $?
        fi
        ;;

*)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/networking {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

`ifupdown` is a script that kills the wpa_supplicant before ifdown is executed (as that script explains so). I don't know shell or bash programming, but as I understood, restart only does ifdown and ifup the interfaces.

**2)** Read the ifup's [man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ifup&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) which says:

> The  ifup  and  ifdown  commands  may be used to configure (or,respectively, deconfigure) network interfaces based on interface  definitions in  the  file  /etc/network/interfaces.

my `/etc/network/interfaces` does not include any configuration about the wpa_supplicant.